# Javascript : "extend" an object without an instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a situation where I have a large, complex object, and I need to re-use it somewhere else with SLIGHT modification (extended properties, etc)

In an effort to improve the simplicity and re-usability, I thought I would try to "extend" the original object. So it looks something like this ...

```
(function ($, window) {
    website.module('admin.models', function (exports, require) {
        exports.item = {
                    // large, complex object that will be instantiated by other things
            };
    });
})(jQuery, window);
```

The library being used is Telerik's `Kendo UI`, and I am using their `MVVM` system. The `item` function is actually an instance of `kendo.data.Model.define` that is being given a template. **[documentation for Kendo.data.Model.define](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model)**

So this is used like ...

```
var item = new website.admin.models.item({
    // specific property values
});
```

This creates a new view model that can be bound to the page. The underlying model has a lot of the behavior, so changing the view model itself does not risk overwriting or changing the underlying core.

This works fine. It moves the functionality I need into a separate file, and cleans up my bigger implementation. This is the expected use of the function as well, outlined by the documentation for the library I am using.

But then there is another model called `schema`, and it is basically identical to `item` except it has a few extra properties.

Rather than copy and paste the item model, I thought it was smarter to just try and extend it. So I attempted this approach...

```
(function ($, window) {
    website.module('admin.models', function (exports, require) {
        exports.schema = $.extend({
               Item: {
                  Id: null, // will be filled in on the UI
                  Name: null, // will be filled in on the UI
                  Description: null, // will be filled in on the UI
                  Timestamp: null // will be filled in on the UI
               },
               Editing: false
        }, website.admin.models.item);
    });
})(jQuery, window);
```

This does not work, though, because the path given is not an instance of "item". But I have been explicitly told I should not use the "new" operator here, either. I simply want to "pull" the actual model from item over, and extend it.

Is there any way to do this? Or is this beyond Javascript's capability?

## Update

The code being used for the 'namespaces' is this;

```
(function (global) {
    var globalNamespace = global['website'];
    var VERSION = '3.0.1';

    function Module() { }

    function numeric(s) {
        if (!s) {
            return 0;
        }
        var a = s.split('.');
        return 10000 * parseInt(a[0]) + 100 * parseInt(a[1]) + parseInt(a[2]);
    }

    if (globalNamespace) {
        if (numeric(VERSION) <= numeric(globalNamespace['VERSION'])) {
            return;
        }
        Module = globalNamespace.constructor;
    } else {
        global['website'] = globalNamespace = new Module();
    }
    globalNamespace['VERSION'] = VERSION;

    function require(path) {
        path = path.replace(/-/g, '_');
        var parts = path.split('.');
        var ns = globalNamespace;
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            if (ns[parts[i]] === undefined) {
                ns[parts[i]] = new Module();
            }
            ns = ns[parts[i]];
        }
        return ns;
    }

    var proto = Module.prototype;

    proto['module'] = function (path, closure) {
        var exports = require(path);
        if (closure) {
            closure(exports, require);
        }
        return exports;
    };

    proto['extend'] = function (exports) {
        for (var sym in exports) {
            if (exports.hasOwnProperty(sym)) {
                this[sym] = exports[sym];
            }
        }
    };
}(this));
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of keys/values that are in `website.admin.models.item`?

Comment: Couldn't you export and use your `var item` that you created? And if so, why not use inheritance, like `exports.schema = Object.create(item);`, then add the properties to the `exports.schema`?

Comment: Sure, I updated the code to show this, it is in the exports.schema part. There will be about 16 more. But the rest of the "item" code doesn't need to be any different. Just ... have some new properties.

Comment: No, I cannot. I explicitly cannot use the `new` operator or pass an instance. That is the behavior of the library. The `item` is an instance of a model class that is part of the library, and you create the model instance as an underlying blueprint, and then later you instantiate it onto an actual view model to use it.

Comment: To make it a bit clearer, I have updated it to explain why I cannot use the `new` operator. It is using `kendo.data.Model.define` - so when I use the new operator, it would not behave as expected. It would create a model within a model (not the desired behavior)

Comment: Is this more along the lines of what you're looking for? (see console) http://jsfiddle.net/2Jw9L/ The one property i added to item was properly added to the schema object. All i changed was i switched to deep copy by adding `true` as the first parameter to $.extend.

Comment: Yes! That is __EXACTLY__ the behavior I am aiming for. I just want to make my code as easy to maintain as possible. Can you post this as an actual answer so I can give proper credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your object contains nested objects, you'll want to use the deep extend. To do that, add `true` as the first parameter to `$.extend`.

```
exports.schema = $.extend(true, {
   Item: {
      Id: null, // will be filled in on the UI
      Name: null, // will be filled in on the UI
      Description: null, // will be filled in on the UI
      Timestamp: null // will be filled in on the UI
   },
   Editing: false
}, website.admin.models.item);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Jw9L/

when you add kendoui, it becomes difficult *(i won't say impossible, there's likely a way to do it that i haven't thought of)* to extend it this way, and easier to just create an object outside of the modules and extend it.

```
var theObj = {
   ...
};

(function ($, window, kendo) {
    ehrpg.module('admin.models', function (exports, require) {
        exports.item = kendo.data.Model.define($.extend(true,{},theObj));
    });
})(jQuery, window, kendo);

(function ($, window, kendo) {
    ehrpg.module('admin.models', function (exports, require) {
        exports.schema = kendo.data.Model.define($.extend(true,{
            Item: {
                Id: null,
                Name: null,
                Dirty: false,
                Timestamp: null
            }
        },theObj));
    });
})(jQuery, window, kendo);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MsrP6/9/

Comment: Yes, yes, a thousand times yes. This is absolutely perfect. This will let me keep the amount of repeated code down a lot, so that when I have to perform maintenance, I am not trying to connect the dots between several different files! Thank you very much, I am so glad that this is doable. I know Javascript is not really an "OOP" language, and I have avoided OOP tendencies where possible, but sometimes they are just more helpful.

Comment: Weird. `website.admin.models.item` is a function... but then it's not. Another option would be to use inheritance, which may (or may not) be desired if there will be modifications to `...item`.

Comment: I am not certain what you mean by inheritance. I thought Javascript did not have inheritance?

Comment: It has prototypal inheritance. It basically works by saying *"If I can't find a property on this object, go look for it on that other object"*.

Comment: This is strange. Your example works on jsFiddle, but when I do the exact same thing in my own code, it doesn't.

Comment: It looks like an object to me, and javascript does have prototype inheritance. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: It looks like an object to me too in your demo, but in the question it shows this: `new website.admin.models.item({...});`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That is the way that Telerik has told me to use `kendo.data.Model.define`.

Comment: And in my code it's not a function, but that's likely because i dont' have all of the plugins installed in the fiddle, which is also probably why it works for me and not you.

Comment: If you will give me a moment, I will make a JSBIN that more accurately represents my actual code.

Comment: Could be that it swaps it out since it has all the information it needs to access that property `website.module('admin.models', ...`

Comment: The difference is probably here: `Module = globalNamespace.constructor;` kendo probably defines that constructor. I've never worked with kendoui, but that's the only place where i see that it could affect the code.

Comment: My guess is the options object will be available as a property on the `website.admin.models.item.prototype`

Comment: Here you go, a jsBin that shows it a bit more clearly : http://jsbin.com/oJaFulOT/1/edit

Comment: What you want is: `ehrpg.admin.models.item.prototype.defaults`

Comment: I am not very fond of it myself, I just have more trouble with jsFiddle.

Comment: using the `prototype.defaults` does not seem to work, either. It still tells me that it is not a function.

Comment: Here, I have packaged it as a jsFiddle that shows the problem I am having better. I am sorry it is messy

Comment: Ah, of course, you're not using kendoui to create schema the same way you are item.

Comment: Hrnm. That does not seem to pass down any of the functions, though.

Comment: odd.. i'm seeing something very weird... all of the properties that were once in item are now in schema, and item is missing a lot of properties...

Comment: Yeah I am seeing that too.. this is extremely odd.

Comment: fields is gone, or more precisely, fields is missing from items, and all properties of fields were given to schema. Looks like defaults isn't what we want.

Comment: It might just be that this isn't possible, and I have to deal with a ton of duplicated code.

Comment: Oh. when i inspect schema and item in the console as properties of ehrpg.admin.models, they both look the same. What's different is their return when you create an instance.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/MsrP6/7/ when you give the schema an id and a name, it works.

Comment: But that still would not pull in the functions from the item model, because they are not part of the fields.

Comment: I don't see the functions you are referring to in the fiddle, is it something in addition to `fields` that you just left off?

Comment: Lines 144 onward. They are outside of "fields". They are just functions.

Comment: Those are inside of fields. But anyway, to get additional properties you'll either have to do it one by one, or scrap this idea and go another route.

Comment: For example, store the setup object outside of all of this and pass it to item, create a copy of it and modify it, then pass the copy to schema.

Comment: What if I made a general object literal that had nothing to do with kendo, and then extneded it?

Comment: Yes! That will work just as well. I'll just have to word things a bit more simplistically. Thank you very much for working on this with me.